# how create a change order(with category) in CA SDM with Rest Api

Tags: rest, ca

how i can create an change order with category in CA Service desk manager from rest api,

now i can create with out category with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><chg id="438969" REL_ATTR="438969" COMMON_NAME="38942"><link href="http://servidor:puerto/caisd-rest/chg/438969" rel="self"/><requestor id="U'CFFF3835E51CA848AD07FB1514B3F628'" REL_ATTR="U'CFFF3835E51CA848AD07FB1514B3F628'" COMMON_NAME="NOmbre User"><link href="http://servidor:puerto/caisd-rest/cnt/U'CFFF3835E51CA848AD07FB1514B3F628'" rel="self"/></requestor><status id="400013" REL_ATTR="IDEA" COMMON_NAME="Registro"><link href="http://servidor:puerto/caisd-rest/chgstat/400013" rel="self"/></status><summary>summary</summary></chg>
```

but when i want create with category i got error 400

Comment: I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the value for the *category* attribute. You can do this by the code of the category, or the common name. Though I think via code is safer.

An example:

```
<chg>
  <summary>Created via REST API</summary>
  <requestor REL_ATTR="U'CFFF3835E51CA848AD07FB1514B3F628'"/>  
  <description>Test desc</description>
  <need_by>1599134400</need_by>
  <call_back_date>1599134400</call_back_date>
  <category REL_ATTR="TST_CAT"/>
  <status COMMON_NAME="OPEN" />
</chg>
```

Maybe you need to supply some other required attributes as well, those depend on your configuration.

Comment: @Mr.P Maybe you could post your sample call, or seek help on the official vendors forum (it improved in recent time).
It also depends on your configuration - maybe you need to set additional required fields, according to your specific customizations.

Comment: In my case i use COMMON_NAME instead of REL_ATTR.